# find number in json array value with regex

Tags: arrays, json, regex, sqlite

i want match string in json string that like:

```
"ids":[44,53,1,3,12,45]
```

i want run query in sqlite send only one digit as `id` and match one of the above `id` in sql statement

i write this regex `"ids":[\[]` for matching start of key
but i don't have any idea to match middle `id` and escape starting `id`

example: 
i have `calc_method` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "calc_method" (
  "calc_method_id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "calc_method_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
  "calc_method_value" TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

in `calc_method_value` column i store `calcMethod` class which convert to json using `Gson`

```
class calcMethod{
    var memberCafeIds:ArrayList<Long>,
    var memberBarIds:ArrayList<Long>
}
```

after i convert `calcMethod` to json i have output like below and this value store in `calc_method_value` column:

```
{"memberCafeIds":[1,2,14,5,44],"memberBarIds":[23,1,5,78]}
```

now i want select row that match to my regex pattern like if `calc_method_value` column have `memberBarIds` with id `1`

```
SELECT * FROM calc_method WHERE calc_method_value REGEXP '"memberCafeIds":\[[:paramId]'
```

`:paramId` is method parameter

Regards, a programmer struggle with regex

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're after. Can you provide us sample output?

Comment: @ctwheels i update my question and add example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sqlite, use [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) functions to work with JSON, not regular expressions. In particular, [`json_each()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach) to turn the JSON array into a table you can query:

```sql
sqlite> CREATE TABLE ex(json);
sqlite> INSERT INTO ex VALUES ('{"ids":[44,53,1,3,12,45]}');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM ex WHERE 1 IN (SELECT value FROM json_each(ex.json, '$.ids'));
json                     
-------------------------
{"ids":[44,53,1,3,12,45]}
sqlite> SELECT * FROM ex WHERE 50 IN (SELECT value FROM json_each(ex.json, '$.ids'));
sqlite>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i update my question and add a example can you see it again. can't do this with regex alone ?

Comment: @123 You'd have to load a sqlite3 extension that provides regular expressions, and no. There's a ton of posts on SO about why regular expressions aren't powerful enough to parse JSON if you look.

Comment: thanks @Shawn, i think use wrong structure and must convert this json to table.